# Show/Hide Password - How can I add this feature?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've looked through the forums but I'm seeing mixed answers especially ones from an old Xcode version.

I only decided to add this after already typing up the code I have in this:
[image: Photo]

How could I go about doing that? I was wanting the 'Eyeball' toggle implemented on the password field.

Comment: I still have not been able to find a simple solution to this. If anyone can guide me with this, that would be fantastic!

Comment: Didn't the solution I've provided work for you?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71214283/how-do-i-programmatically-set-secure-text-field-and-normal-text-field-in-swiftui/71214666#71214666

Answer (score 57):

[image]You can simply use this view instead of `SecureField`. It has the eye icon inside, so for most cases you don't need to care about anything.

```
struct SecureInputView: View {
    
    @Binding private var text: String
    @State private var isSecured: Bool = true
    private var title: String
    
    init(_ title: String, text: Binding<String>) {
        self.title = title
        self._text = text
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .trailing) {
            Group {
                if isSecured {
                    SecureField(title, text: $text)
                } else {
                    TextField(title, text: $text)
                }
            }.padding(.trailing, 32)

            Button(action: {
                isSecured.toggle()
            }) {
                Image(systemName: self.isSecured ? "eye.slash" : "eye")
                    .accentColor(.gray)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Copy paste this view into your app, and instead of `SecureField` just use `SecureInputView`.

Example: `SecureInputView("Password", text: $viewModel.password)`

Comment: There are 3 issues with this solution.
1. the secureField is cleared if you enter text, tap on show password, tap on hide password, and enter text again.
2. when tapping on show password the keyboard is dismissed.
3. Using a ZStack will have text be written under the button.

Comment: @MihaiGeorgescu did you find out how to use it without this problems?

Answer (score 19):

For those still looking for a simple solution to this issue (requires iOS 15 for swiftUI 3):

With the new `@FocusState` introduced in swiftUI 3, it's possible to keep focus and keyboard open while changing State.

By using the `opacity` modifier instead of conditionally changing between SecureField and TextField, the focus can jump between the two without issues with the keyboard.

This allows you to toggle between revealing and hiding the password with the the eye button included in the ZStack.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SecureTextFieldWithReveal: View {

@FocusState var focus1: Bool
@FocusState var focus2: Bool
@State var showPassword: Bool = false
@State var text: String = ""

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        ZStack(alignment: .trailing) {
            TextField("Password", text: $text)
                .modifier(LoginModifier())
                .textContentType(.password)
                .focused($focus1)
                .opacity(showPassword ? 1 : 0)
            SecureField("Password", text: $text)
                .modifier(LoginModifier())
                .textContentType(.password)
                .focused($focus2)
                .opacity(showPassword ? 0 : 1)
            Button(action: {
                showPassword.toggle()
                if showPassword { focus1 = true } else { focus2 = true }
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: self.showPassword ? "eye.slash.fill" : "eye.fill").font(.system(size: 16, weight: .regular))
                    .padding()
            })
        }
    }
}
}
```

[Password field hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ju4TK.png)

[Password field revealed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOvnd.png)

This is the code in `LoginModifier`:

```
import SwiftUI

struct LoginModifier: ViewModifier {

var borderColor: Color = Color.gray

func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
        .disableAutocorrection(true)
        .autocapitalization(.none)
        .padding()
        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(borderColor, lineWidth: 1))
}
}
```

The only issue I've had with this method is that on regaining focus `SecureField` will automatically clear any text already entered if you start typing. This seems to be a design choice by Apple.

Comment: There is still a issue that cursor is not showing after toggle

Comment: One another issue when you press Tab key on your mac its not moving focus for first attempt

Comment: An issue here is you can't use @StateFocus for your own needs using SecureTextFieldWithReveal.

Comment: thanks, this solution works perfectly. but there is one issue: after toggling on the "Save Password" feature stops working, and I'm not sure why (tried setting focus on SecureField programmatically, etc.)

Comment: UPD. I have found a workaround for missing “Save Password” promt by setting opacity to 0.001 
  .opacity(showPassword ? 0.001 : 1)

Answer (score 17):

The possible approach is to show either TextField or SecureField joined to one storage, like in below demo:

#### Updated: Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

with `FocusState`, now it is possible to change fields without having the keyboard disappear

[image: demo2]

Main part:

```
if showPassword {
    TextField("Placeholer", text: $password)
        .focused($inFocus, equals: .plain)
} else {
    SecureField("Placeholder", text: $password)
        .focused($inFocus, equals: .secure)
}
Button("toggle") {
    self.showPassword.toggle()
    inFocus = showPassword ? .plain : .secure
}
```

[Test module in project is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestSwitchSecureField.swift)

#### Old:

```
struct DemoShowPassword: View {
    @State private var showPassword: Bool = false
    @State private var password = "demo"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if showPassword {
                TextField("Placeholer", text: $password)
            } else {
                SecureField("Placeholder", text: $password)
            }
            Button("toggle") {
                self.showPassword.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm still a complete noob. Is this added to the code as is? (assuming not)

Comment: there's a problem with this approach. If the keyboard is shown and you press the toggle button, it will dismiss the keyboard, as now a different Field gets shown

Comment: Another problem is TextField allows third-party keyboards to access that field, while SecureField does not. IMO makes sensitive data handled by SecureField insecure and threatens user's privacy. See my answer below for details.

Comment: This solution resets the text when you toggle to secure mode. 

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution that meets the following requirements.
Requires iOS 15+, tested on iOS 15.0 (simulator) and 16.4 (device).

1. The keyboard stays open
2. The save password to keychain (for autofill) action sheet doesn't show when switching modes
3. The cursor shows in both modes
4. The textfield doesn't clear when switching back to the secure mode. (it will clear if typing after switching to secure mode though)
5. The field can be focused externally.
6. If the field isn't focused then switching modes won't focus it
7. As a bonus, if the app goes into the background it will switch to secure mode

```swift
struct PasswordField: View {

    let placeholder: String

    @Binding
    var text: String

    @State
    private var showText: Bool = false

    private enum Focus {
        case secure, text
    }

    @FocusState
    private var focus: Focus?

    @Environment(\.scenePhase)
    private var scenePhase

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ZStack {
                SecureField(placeholder, text: $text)
                    .focused($focus, equals: .secure)
                    .opacity(showText ? 0 : 1)
                TextField(placeholder, text: $text)
                    .focused($focus, equals: .text)
                    .opacity(showText ? 1 : 0)
            }

            Button(action: {
                showText.toggle()
            }) {
                Image(systemName: showText ? "eye.slash.fill" : "eye.fill")
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: focus) { newValue in
            // if the PasswordField is focused externally, then make sure the correct field is actually focused
            if newValue != nil {
                focus = showText ? .text : .secure
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newValue in
            if newValue != .active {
                showText = false
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: showText) { newValue in
            if focus != nil { // Prevents stealing focus to this field if another field is focused, or nothing is focused
                DispatchQueue.main.async { // Needed for general iOS 16 bug with focus
                    focus = newValue ? .text : .secure
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It can be used like so, where the focus state for the form will work correctly.

```swift
struct LoginView: View {

    private enum Focus {
        case email, password
    }

    @FocusState
    private var focus: Focus?

    @State
    private var email: String = ""

    @State
    private var password: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("your@email.com", text: $email)
                .focused($focus, equals: .email)
            PasswordField(placeholder: "*****", text: $password)
                .focused($focus, equals: .password)
        }
        .onSubmit {
            if focus == .email {
                focus = .password
            } else if focus == .password {
                // do login
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to prevent clearing the textfield when switching back to secure mode ?

Comment: The code in my answer should do that.

Comment: I tried this but it seems to clear. My scenario is I type some text in secure mode, I switch to regular mode and I can add more text. If I switch back to secure mode and start typing, it clears the textfield and starts again.

Comment: @ShawnFrank ah yeah I put that in my answer that if you start typing after switching it will clear. that is unavoidable as far as I've found, any password textfield will clear if it loses and then gain focus its just a system behavior.

Comment: This is actually great solution. But I'm wondering about that SecureField behavior, any chance not to clear if typing after switch?

Answer (score 6):

I am afraid most answers here fail to mention that switching from `SecureField` to `TextField` reduces security. `SecureField` is essentially, per Apple documentation, simply a `TextField` where user input is masked [1]. However, `SecureField` also does one other job - it prevents using third-party keyboards (keyboard extensions) and thus protects user's security and privacy.

Ideal solution would be to have input field that is both "secure" and has `mask()`/`unmask()` methods. Unfortunately, the only advice I found is when you want to implement unmasking as other answers suggested, at least block third-party keyboards from your application entirely [2]:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier extensionPointIdentifier: UIApplication.ExtensionPointIdentifier) -> Bool {
        return extensionPointIdentifier != UIApplication.ExtensionPointIdentifier.keyboard
    }
}
@main
struct MyApplication: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Should also mention that `UIApplicationDelegate` is part of UIKit, not SwiftUI. There is no "native" SwiftUI for the same purpose as for now, although the above works fine for now.

1. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/securefield
2. https://www.securing.pl/en/third-party-iphone-keyboards-vs-your-ios-application-security/

Answer (score 4):

@Derwrecked's answer really gave me some good inspirations: instead using two TextField, change `SecureField` opacity and show/hide a `Text` can avoid keyboard dismissing problem, but in his answer that long `TouchDownUpEventModifier` seems unnecessarily complicated, you can easily achieve the same effect using a `Button` with label.

So below is my approach, and the previews look like this
[image]

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct SecureInput: View {
    let placeholder: String
    @State private var showText: Bool = false
    @State var text: String
    var onCommit: (()->Void)?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            ZStack {
                SecureField(placeholder, text: $text, onCommit: {
                    onCommit?()
                })
                .opacity(showText ? 0 : 1)
                
                if showText {
                    HStack {
                        Text(text)
                            .lineLimit(1)
                        
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                showText.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: showText ? "eye.slash.fill" : "eye.fill")
            })
            .accentColor(.secondary)
        }
        .padding()
        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                    .stroke(Color.secondary, lineWidth: 1)
                    .foregroundColor(.clear))
    }
    
}

struct SecureInput_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            SecureInput(placeholder: "Any placeholder", text: "")
                .padding()
                .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 400, height: 100))
            
            SecureInput(placeholder: "Any placeholder", text: "")
                .padding()
                .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
                .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 400, height: 100))
        }
    }
}
```

- An known issue for this approach: since when password is shown, `SecureField` has 0.0 opacity, so input cursor is not visible. But users can still keep typing without losing keyboard focus, so I find it acceptable, if anyone has a solution for this, please comment and share.

Comment: Editing is possible while enabled/showing the text.

Comment: @daniel-hu super old answer, but I kind of solved the known issue but "just" using a TextField instead of just Text .when isShown = true.

Comment: The cursor is lost between toggles 

Answer (score 3):

For those that do not want the keyboard disappearing while typing:

```
struct CustomSecureField: View {
    @State var password: String = ""
    @State var isShowingPassword: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ZStack{
                HStack{
                    SecureField(
                        isShowingPassword ? "" : "Password",
                        text: $password) {
                        
                    }.opacity(isShowingPassword ? 0 : 1)
                    // show only one of these is not empty.
                    if(!password.isEmpty){
                        Image(systemName: isShowingPassword ? "eye.slash" : "eye")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(width: 20, height: 20, alignment: .center)
                            .modifier(TouchDownUpEventModifier(changeState: { (buttonState) in
                                if buttonState == .pressed {
                                    isShowingPassword = true
                                } else {
                                    isShowingPassword = false
                                }
                            }))
                    }
                }
                if(isShowingPassword){
                    HStack{
                        Text(password)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .allowsHitTesting(false)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
        }.padding(10)
        .background(Color.gray)
    }
}
```

and the on tap and release modifier:

```
public enum ButtonState {
    case pressed
    case notPressed
}

/// ViewModifier allows us to get a view, then modify it and return it
public struct TouchDownUpEventModifier: ViewModifier {
    
    /// Properties marked with `@GestureState` automatically resets when the gesture ends/is cancelled
    /// for example, once the finger lifts up, this will reset to false
    /// this functionality is handled inside the `.updating` modifier
    @GestureState private var isPressed = false
    
    /// this is the closure that will get passed around.
    /// we will update the ButtonState every time your finger touches down or up.
    let changeState: (ButtonState) -> Void
    
    /// a required function for ViewModifier.
    /// content is the body content of the caller view
    public func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        
        /// declare the drag gesture
        let drag = DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
            
            /// this is called whenever the gesture is happening
            /// because we do this on a `DragGesture`, this is called when the finger is down
            .updating($isPressed) { (value, gestureState, transaction) in
                
            /// setting the gestureState will automatically set `$isPressed`
            gestureState = true
        }
        
        return content
        .gesture(drag) /// add the gesture
        .onChange(of: isPressed, perform: { (pressed) in /// call `changeState` whenever the state changes
            /// `onChange` is available in iOS 14 and higher.
            if pressed {
                self.changeState(.pressed)
            } else {
                self.changeState(.notPressed)
            }
        })
    }
    
    /// if you're on iPad Swift Playgrounds and you put all of this code in a seperate file,
    /// you need to add a public init so that the compiler detects it.
    public init(changeState: @escaping (ButtonState) -> Void) {
        self.changeState = changeState
    }
}
```

From what I have seen there is no easy way to keep the text showing unless you want to lose focus on your text.

Cheers!

Comment: Does this avoid loss of cursor between toggles?

Answer (score 3):

This solution is suitable for iOS 14 and higher.

inputValue - Is a real input which a user enter
visibleInput - A user sees it in the text field

```
import SwiftUI

struct SecureInputView: View {
    @Binding var inputValue: String
    
    @State private var visibleInput: String = "" 
    @State private var isSecured = true
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .trailing) {
            TextField("Password", text: $visibleInput)
                .onChange(of: visibleInput) { newValue in
                    guard isSecured else { inputValue = newValue; return }
                    if newValue.count >= inputValue.count {
                        let newItem = newValue.filter { $0 != Character("●") }
                        inputValue.append(newItem)
                    } else {
                        inputValue.removeLast()
                    }
                    visibleInput = String(newValue.map { _ in Character("●") })
                }
            Button {
                isSecured.toggle()
                visibleInput = isSecured ? String(inputValue.map { _ in Character("●") }) :  inputValue
            } label: {
                (isSecured ? Image(systemName: "eye") : Image(systemName: "eye.slash"))
                    .tint(.gray)
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var password = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        SecureInputView(inputValue: $password)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: One minor anoyance with this solution is that the cursor position is reset to the end on toggle. But I think it should be possible to restore correct cursor position by storing it before toggling and setting it after.

Comment: If textfield is not of "password" type, it will allow weird characters as password, like emojis... right?

Comment: @EzequielAdrian yes, just replace "●" with emoji

Answer (score 2):

I am using this approach for now in my current application. I would like to say that it works flawlessly.

```
@ViewBuilder
    func secureField() -> some View {
        if self.showPassword {
            TextField("Password", text: $passwordText)
                .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .regular, design: .default))
                .keyboardType(.default)
                .autocapitalization(.none)
                .disableAutocorrection(true)
                .frame(maxWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, maxHeight: 60, alignment: .center)
        } else {
            SecureField("Password", text: $passwordText)
                .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .regular, design: .default))
                .keyboardType(.default)
                .autocapitalization(.none)
                .disableAutocorrection(true)
                .frame(maxWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, maxHeight: 60, alignment: .center)
        }
    }
```

Use:

```
HStack{
    Image(systemName: "lock.fill")
        .foregroundColor(passwordText.isEmpty ? .secondary : .primary)
        .font(.system(size: 18, weight: .medium, design: .default))
        .frame(width: 18, height: 18, alignment: .center)
    secureField()
    if !passwordText.isEmpty {
        Button(action: {
            self.showPassword.toggle()
        }, label: {
            ZStack(alignment: .trailing){
                Color.clear
                    .frame(maxWidth: 29, maxHeight: 60, alignment: .center)
                Image(systemName: self.showPassword ? "eye.slash.fill" : "eye.fill")
                    .font(.system(size: 18, weight: .medium))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.init(red: 160.0/255.0, green: 160.0/255.0, blue: 160.0/255.0))
            }
        })
    }
}
.padding(.horizontal, 15)
.background(Color.primary.opacity(0.05).cornerRadius(10))
.padding(.horizontal, 15)
```

Comment: This is the best answer IMO!

Comment: The only change I would suggest to make things even simpler is to use .overlay() instead of the ZStack for the toggle. It'd look something like this:
.overlay(
                        Image(systemName: showPassword ? "eye.slash.fill" : "eye.fill")
                            .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .medium))
                            .foregroundColor(Color.theme.lightGray)
                            .padding()
                            .onTapGesture { showPassword.toggle() }
                        , alignment: .trailing
                    )

Comment: This plus @blrsk's addition is very good as it shows the eye icon inside the password field but there's an issue that it clashes with the text if the input text is very long.

Comment: You can add .padding(.trailing) to your textfield to remedy that

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking for a nice solution for my use-case. I had to have an indicator which field is in focus. Successfully done that with onEditingChanged from TextField, but SecureField doesn't provide that closure. I tried stacking them both and disabling the SecureField so it only shows 'hidden' characters. That resulted in cursor sticking to the TextField text while SecureField text had different text width which made it seem buggy. Imagine a password with a lot of I's in it. The idea is to have a main binding with two side bindings that update the main one and sync each other.

```
struct CustomSecureField : View {
    var label : String
    @Binding var text : String
    @State var isEditing = false
    @State var isHidden = true
    var body : some View {
        let showPasswordBinding = Binding<String> {
            self.text
        } set: {
            self.text = $0
        }
        let hidePasswordBinding = Binding<String> {
            String.init(repeating: "●", count: self.text.count)
        } set: { newValue in
            if(newValue.count < self.text.count) {
                self.text = ""
            } else {
                self.text.append(contentsOf: newValue.suffix(newValue.count - self.text.count) )
            }
        }

        return ZStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                TextField(
                    label,
                    text: isHidden ? hidePasswordBinding : showPasswordBinding,
                    onEditingChanged: { editingChanged in
                        isEditing = editingChanged
                    }
                )
                Image("eye").frame(width: 50, height: 50).onTapGesture {
                    isHidden.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very nice workaround if you have to support < iOS 15 and can't use `@FocusState`. And this works perfectly if you have your usual user who removes and adds characters only at the end of string, not middle. BUT! 
SwiftUI's `SecureField` doesn't support that either. When user tries to remove any character - at beginning, middle or end - the whole field gets removed. So change `self.text = String(self.text.dropLast())` to `self.text = ""` and you get yourself nice clean version of `SecuredField` behavior without having to switch between fields, apply opacity or lose cursor. Nice job!

Comment: Nice catch! @roxanneM

Answer (score 2):

[@Vahagn Gevorgyan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66402146/5948104) answer was almost correct but some people were struggling with maintaining state... this is because the field is using a binding which should ideally be held in a parent view. Therefore just update the bindings to state variables like this

```
struct SecureInputView: View {
    
    let placeholder: String
    
    @State var text: String
    @State var isSecure: Bool = true
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .trailing) {
            Group {
                if isSecure {
                    SecureField(placeholder, text: $text)
                } else {
                    TextField(placeholder, text: $text)
                }
            }.padding(.trailing, 32)
            Button {
                isSecure.toggle()
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: isSecure ? "lock.fill" : "lock.open")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@State private var isPasswordVisible = false

ZStack {
    TextField("", text: $password)
          .opacity(isPasswordVisible ? 1 : 0)

    SecureField("", text: $password)
           .opacity(isPasswordVisible ? 0 : 1)
}
```

1. It doesn't need @Focus from iOS 15
2. Keyboard will not disappear/appear on changing `isPasswordVisible`
3. Password will not cleared on changing from visible to invisible then typing

Good Luck

Comment: There is still a issue that cursor is not showing after toggle

Comment: @SPatel that's correct. you should try `UITextField` if that cursor thing is a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

Crazy (AKA don't use in production) and very breakable solution here (but working at the time of writing):

```swift
extension TextField {
    
    public func secure(_ secure: Bool = true) -> TextField {
        if secure {
            var secureField = self
            withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &secureField) { pointer in
                let offset = 32
                let valuePointer = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating: pointer)
                    .assumingMemoryBound(to: Bool.self)
                    .advanced(by: offset)
                valuePointer.pointee = true
            }
            return secureField
        } else {
            return self
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```swift
@State securing = true

...

TextField(...)
    .secure(securing)
```

Comment: How did you find offset 32? what happens if it was not in that position

Comment: Will not work if TextField has `axis: .vertical`

Answer (score 1):

I put everything into a TextFieldStyle

```
struct AppTextFieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    var label: String = ""
    @Binding var fieldValue: String
    var placeholderText: String = ""
    var systemImage: String?
    var isPassword: Bool = false
    @State var showPassword = false
    @Binding var hasError: Bool
    @Binding var validationMessage: String
    
    func _body(configuration: TextField<Self._Label>) -> some View {
        VStack(spacing: 5) {
            HStack {
                Text(label)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                Spacer()
            }
            HStack {
                HStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: 0) {
                    if let systemImage {
                        Image(systemName: systemImage)
                            .font(.headline)
                            .foregroundColor(
                                Color.gray.opacity(0.7))
                            .padding(.trailing, 10)
                    }
                    HStack {
                        if isPassword && showPassword {
                            TextField(placeholderText, text: self.$fieldValue)
                        } else {
                            configuration
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(minHeight: 23) // for some reason the textfield is not same height as secure textfield
                    if isPassword {
                        Button(
                            action: {
                                showPassword.toggle()
                            },
                            label: {
                                Image(systemName: self.showPassword ? "eye.slash" : "eye")
                                    .accentColor(.gray)
                            }
                        )
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(hasError ? .red : .gray.opacity(0.70))
                        .padding(.leading, 10)
                    }
                }
                .padding(.all, 10)
                .background(colorScheme == .dark ?
                            LinearGradient(
                                gradient: AppGradients.DarkTextFieldGradient.getGradient(),
                                startPoint: .top,
                                endPoint: .bottom
                            ) : nil)
                .background(colorScheme != .dark ? Color.white : nil)
            }
            .cornerRadius(10)
            // .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.40), radius: 2, x: 1, y: 1)
            .overlay {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .stroke(
                        hasError ? .red : .gray.opacity(0.90), lineWidth: 1)
            }
            .padding(.top, 5)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            if hasError {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.triangle.fill")
                        .font(.headline)
                    Text(validationMessage)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .font(.footnote)
                }.foregroundColor(.red)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then I use it like so

```
TextField("test", text: self.$email)
                .textFieldStyle(
                    AppTextFieldStyle(
                        label: "Email",
                        fieldValue: self.$email,
                        systemImage: "person.circle",
                        hasError: .constant(true),
                        validationMessage: .constant("Please enter your email")
                    )
                )
                .focused($focus, equals: .email)
                .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
                .privacySensitive()
                .disableAutocorrection(true)
            //
            SecureField("password", text: self.$password)
                .textFieldStyle(
                    AppTextFieldStyle(
                        label: "Password",
                        fieldValue: self.$password,
                        placeholderText: "password",
                        systemImage: "lock.circle",
                        isPassword: true,
                        hasError: .constant(false),
                        validationMessage: .constant("please enter your password")
                    )
                )
                .focused($focus, equals: .password)
                .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
                .privacySensitive()
                .disableAutocorrection(true)
```

btw the focus state is defined in the form view

```
enum FocusableField: Hashable {
        case email
        case password
    }
    @FocusState private var focus: FocusableField?
```

Comment: This was missing some parts like the gradient so I added the missing pieces and made a runnable example in a gist here: https://gist.github.com/eonist/b90d3193320f5fb1a576de6f2dc842a2

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by Jonathan and others works great, except for one minor issue with the Autofill feature. After you interact with “eye” button, the “Save Password” prompt stop working, so you can use old hack with 0.001 opacity

```
   ZStack {
                TextField(placeholder, text: $text)
                    .focused($fieldToFocus, equals: .text)
                    .opacity(shouldShowTextField ? 1 : 0.001)
                SecureField(placeholder, text: $text)
                    .textContentType(.password)
                    .focused($fieldToFocus, equals: .secure)
                    .opacity(shouldShowTextField ? 0.001 : 1)
            }
```

The reason behind that setting opacity to zero remove View from View Tree, and we don’t want to do it here.
Please, not that only SecureField marked as `.password` for textContentType

Answer (score -1):

I made a custom text field that combine `SecureField` and `TextField`.
[This is an example where I used my custom field for both email and pwd.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifwp2.png)

This is my solution:

```
struct CustomTextField: View {
    let imageName: String
    let placeholderText: String
    
    var isSecureInput: Bool = false ///< define if this text field is secured and require eye button
    
    @State private var isSecured: Bool
    
    @Binding var text: String
    
    init(image: String,
         placeholder: String,
         text: Binding<String>,
         isSecureInput: Bool) {
        imageName = image
        placeholderText = placeholder
        self._text = text
        self.isSecureInput = isSecureInput
        isSecured = isSecureInput
        
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: imageName)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(.darkGray))
                
                if isSecureInput {
                    Group {
                        if isSecured {
                            SecureField(placeholderText, text: $text)
                        }
                        else {
                            TextField(text, text: $text)
                        }
                    }
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                    .textContentType(.password)
                    
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        isSecured.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: self.isSecured ? "eye.slash" : "eye")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.darkGray))
                    }
                }
                
                else {
                    TextField(placeholderText, text: $text)
                }
            }
            
            Divider()
        }
    }
}
```