# How do I programmatically set secure text field and normal text field in swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

SwiftUI has two different forms of text fields, one is SecureField which hides input and TextField which doesn't hide input. Instead of creating two separate views, is there a way to create a single view that takes in a parameter to create both types while repeating as little code as possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just make a `View` with all the code you want for the `SecureTextField` and the `TextField` then all you have to do is call the `HybridTextField` where ever you need it.

```
import SwiftUI
struct HybridTextFieldUsageView: View {
    @State var password: String = "password"
    var body: some View {
        //Use this anywhere in your code
        HybridTextField(text: $password, titleKey: "password")
    }
}
///Contains all the code for the Secure and regular TextFields
struct HybridTextField: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    @State var isSecure: Bool = true
    var titleKey: String
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Group{
                if isSecure{
                    SecureField(titleKey, text: $text)
                    
                }else{
                    TextField(titleKey, text: $text)
                }
            }.textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.2), value: isSecure)
            //Add any common modifiers here so they dont have to be repeated for each Field
            Button(action: {
                isSecure.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: !isSecure ? "eye.slash" : "eye" )
            })
        }//Add any modifiers shared by the Button and the Fields here
    }
}

struct HybridTextField_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HybridTextFieldUsageView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! I think the missing gap for me was that group view. I was at a loss for how to have the two fields and not repeat modifiers but this makes a lot more sense now, thanks for the example.

Comment: No problem you can even put the modifiers on the hybrid view declaration like in the usage view if you have modifiers that would only apply to a single view.

Comment: Very amazing example

Answer (score 0):

I create a custom view for PasswordTextField. May be this code will help. I don't know either it helps you, though it fulfilled my requirement. That's why sharing it to you. This is the output of my code

[image]

```
struct PasswordTextField: View {
    
    @Binding var isPasswordVisible: Bool
    var hint: String
    @Binding var text: String
    var isTextChanged: (Bool) -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if isPasswordVisible {
                TextFieldView(
                    hint: hint,
                    text: $text,
                    isTextChanged: isTextChanged
                )
            } else {
                SecuredTextFieldView(
                    hint: hint,
                    text: $text
                )
            }
        }.overlay(alignment: .trailing) {
            Image(systemName: isPasswordVisible ? "eye.fill" : "eye.slash.fill")
                .padding()
                .onTapGesture {
                    isPasswordVisible.toggle()
                }
        }
        
    }
}

struct TextFieldView: View {
    
    var hint: String
    @Binding var text: String
    var isTextChanged: (Bool) -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField(
            hint,
            text: $text,
            onEditingChanged: isTextChanged
        )
        .padding()
        .overlay(
            Rectangle().strokeBorder(
                .gray.opacity(0.2),
                style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2.0)
            )
        )
    }
}

struct SecuredTextFieldView: View {
    
    var hint: String
    @Binding var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        SecureField(
            hint,
            text: $text
        )
        .padding()
        .overlay(
            Rectangle().strokeBorder(
                .gray.opacity(0.2),
                style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2.0)
            )
        )
    }
}
```

and call the custom view in your actual view

```
struct PasswordView: View {
    
    @State var password: String = ""
    @State var confirmPassword: String = ""
    @State var isPasswordVisible: Bool = false
    @State var isConfirmPasswordVisible: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 15) {

            Text("New Password")
                .font(.headline)
                .fontWeight(.regular)
                .padding(.top, 30)
            
            PasswordTextField(
                isPasswordVisible: $isPasswordVisible,
                hint: "Password having 8 charecture",
                text: $password,
                isTextChanged: { (changed) in
                    
                }
            )
            
            Text("Confirm New Password")
                .font(.headline)
                .fontWeight(.regular)
                .padding(.top, 10)
            
            PasswordTextField(
                isPasswordVisible: $isConfirmPasswordVisible,
                hint: "Password having 8 charecture",
                text: $confirmPassword,
                isTextChanged: { (changed) in
                    
                }
            )

            Spacer()
            
        }.padding(.horizontal, 25)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In your view's body you can use a ternary to create the right textfield as needed without using a giant if/else block:

```
(self.isSecure ? AnyView(SecureField(placeholder, text: $value)) : AnyView(TextField(placeholder, text: $value)))
```

This will return a view that you can use operators on, which is useful if you're creating a custom text input. For example, the following would be painful if we had to do it twice for each kind of text field. Using a ternary in the actual view body keeps you from having two giant if/else blocks.

```
    VStack {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(placeholder)
                .foregroundColor(Color(.placeholderText))
                .offset(y: $value.wrappedValue.isEmpty ? 0 : -25)
                .scaleEffect($value.wrappedValue.isEmpty ? 1 : 0.8, anchor: .leading)
            (self.isSecure ? AnyView(SecureField(placeholder, text: $value)) : AnyView(TextField(placeholder, text: $value)))
                .onChange(of: self.value) { newValue in
                    if self.onChange(newValue) != true {
                        self.value = previousValue
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.previousValue = newValue
                    }
                }
        }
        .padding(.top, 15)
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.2))
        Divider()
         .frame(height: 1)
         .padding(.horizontal, 30)
         .background(Color.black)
    }
```

Comment: `AnyView` is discouraged by Apple https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10022

Comment: ternary operations for `View`s are also notorious for being slow (long build times) and causing crashes https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=swiftui%20ternary

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the comments w/ sources. I'll definitely go back and revise this then!