# How to optimize applying properties in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

How can this SwiftUI code be optimized so that `.foregroundColor(.red)` doesn't have to be repeated?

```swift
if let image = image {
    Label("ok", systemImage: image).foregroundColor(.red)
} else {
    Text("ok").foregroundColor(.red)
}
```

Comment: Wrap the conditional in a Group and apply the modifier to the Group

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I programmatically set secure text field and normal text field in swiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71214283/how-do-i-programmatically-set-secure-text-field-and-normal-text-field-in-swiftui)

Comment: What is `Label("ok")`? That is not a `Label` initialiser I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could just wrap your conditional in a `Group`. Here is an example:

```swift
Group {
    if let image = image {
        Label("ok", systemImage: image)
    } else {
        Label("ok")
    }
}.foregroundColor(.red)
```

*Credits to @mr-developer for originally posting the answer.*