Keyboard is dismissing when TextField is changed to secureField and vice versa Using FocusState
I trying to make my textField to secureField but inProcess When I tapped on eye button. Keyboard is getting dismissed, which I don't want. Here is the code I wrote
import SwiftUI

enum TextFieldTypes {
    case name
    case password
}

struct SecureFieldTest: View {
    @State var name: String = ""
    @State var password: String = ""
    @State var isEyeSlashed: Bool = false
    @FocusState var focusState: TextFieldTypes?
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MyTextField(placeHolder: "name",
                        text: $name,
                        focusState: $focusState,
                        currentFocuState: .name,
                        nextFocusState: .password)
            
            MyTextField(placeHolder: "password",
                        text: $password,
                        focusState: $focusState,
                        currentFocuState: .password,
                        nextFocusState: .name)
        }
        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
    }
}

struct MyTextField: View {
    var placeHolder: String
    @Binding var text: String
    @FocusState.Binding var focusState: TextFieldTypes?
    @State var currentFocuState: TextFieldTypes
    @State var nextFocusState: TextFieldTypes
    @State var isEyeSlashed: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if isEyeSlashed {
                SecureField(placeHolder, text: $text)
            } else {
                TextField(placeHolder, text: $text)
            }
            Image(systemName: isEyeSlashed ? "eye.slash": "eye")
                .onTapGesture {
                    isEyeSlashed.toggle()
                }
        }
        .focused($focusState, equals: currentFocuState)
        .onSubmit {
            focusState = nextFocusState
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    SecureFieldTest()
}

I am thinking that i have to implement my own secureField instead of swiftUi's one. Any other solutions?

could you check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/76369073/2179571
